How to tell when Fullcalendar v6 has finished rendering events?
I have an app that uses Fullcalendar v6 and it is working.  I would like to have a "glass panel" pop up whenever FC starts loading events and after the events are completely rendered.
When I add or cancel events (after the related ajax calls finish) I call refetchEvents().  The events: function(info, successCallback, failureCallback) method is triggered and I use that to get the updated list of events from storage.  These are passed to the successCallback().  At some point after that the eventSourceSuccess: function(view) method is called.
I turn on a glass paned just before refetchEvents() and turn it off in eventSourceSuccess (or ...Failure).  However, in most cases, events are still being rendered to the display after the glass panel is gone.  Sometimes many seconds after.
Are there other events I should be capturing to tell me when ALL event renders are finished?

Unfortunately there's no such feature at the moment AFAIK. Perhaps you can request it; https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features . Although if it's taking several seconds to render all your events after they've finished downloading then it suggests you have a lot of events going into your calendar - maybe too many for it to be comprehensible to a user?

Also are you ensuring you only download the events which will actually be visible on the calendar for the chosen date range, and not just dumping out your entire database of historical and future events that the user will probably never scroll to? As I'm sure you're aware fullcalendar gives you the start and end dates of the currently-displayed data range into the events function, so you can pass them to your server to filter the returned list of events.

This app is a device reservation system in a laboratory environment.  There can be lots of events per view.  I do limit the DB search to the view date boundaries.

Maybe there needs to be an additional way for users to filter the events down to a manageable quantity - e.g. maybe by types of equipment, or something like that? Obviously I don't know the details of the scenario, I was merely pointing out that if you have sufficient events rendering that it performs as slowly as that, then you may also have a UX problem to go with it. If there are hundreds of events on the calendar at once, or something like that, then it's inevitably going to be pretty baffling for anyone trying to read it.

I dig it.  Thank you
